# Python and MechanicalSoup: variable null after loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanicalsoup

I have a problem and I don't know its a python problem or a problem of MechanicalSoup:

```
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("http://mypage.com")
  for item in mylist:
    browser.follow_link(...)
    #do some stuff with the data
    ...
browser.follow_link('logout') # error browser null now
```

When I use the browser object after the loop, the object is null. I also get this message later:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method StatefulBrowser.__del__ of <mechanicalsoup.stateful_browser.StatefulBrowser object at 0x7f27b27cc4e0>>
```

I am using Python 3.4.3 and  MechanicalSoup 0.9.

Answer (score 0):

A Python variable cannot become null without being assigned. First, check that it is actually null by adding this after the loop:

```
assert browser is null
```

If it is actually null, then you'll have to pay your actual code if you want help. If the code itself is too messy or too long, please reproduce your issue on a minimalistic self contained example.